# Python function message formatter

Tags: python

I have a task to develop a function that takes in a string message and returns an array of string messages with pagination if needed. For this exercise, the maximum number of characters in the input message is 160. Also, do not break words into syllables and hyphens.

my function hasn't satisfied the functionality of not breaking words into syllables

```
def sms_format(message, size):
    sms_text = []
    if len(message) == 0:
        return sms_text

    text = list(message)

    if len(text) <= size:
        new_text = ''.join(text)
        sms_text.append(new_text)

    elif len(text) > size:
        while len(text)>size:
            texts = ''.join(text[:size])
            sms_text.append(texts)
            text = text[size:]

        sms_text.append(''.join(text))

    return(sms_text)


message = "Your task is to develop a function that takes"


print(sms_format(message, 20))
```

actual results:
`['Your task is to deve', 'lop a function that ', 'takes']`

expected result:
it should not break the words

Comment: What part of you code is making any attempt to not split words?

Comment: By not breaking the words, do you intend to get a straight string?

Comment: Is your expected output `['Your task is to ', 'develop a function ', 'that takes']`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work OK:

```py
def sms_format(message, size):
    result = []
    words = message.split()
    chunk = words.pop(0)

    for word in words:
        if len(chunk + word) >= size:
            result.append(chunk)
            chunk = word
        else:
            chunk = " ".join((chunk, word))

    result.append(chunk)
    return result

message = "Your task is to develop a function that takes long text, and splits it into chunks."
print(sms_format(message, 20))
```

Gives:

```
['Your task is to', 'develop a function', 'that takes long', 'text, and splits it', 'into chunks.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Update elif block:

```py
elif len(text) > size:
        current_size = size
        while len(text)>size:
            texts = ''.join(text[:current_size])
            if texts[-1] == ' ' or text[:size + 1] == ' ': 
                sms_text.append(texts)
                text = text[current_size:]
                current_size = size
            else:
                current_size = current_size - 1
```

```
Output : ['Your task is to ', 'develop a function ', 'that takes']
```